# Check if data exist in second table

Tags: mysql, left-join, outer-join

I have four tables `Transaction`, `Merchant`, `onlineuser` and `onlineuserhistory`.
When the user goes into the `onlinesite` we create one row for that user in `onlineuser` table with `entry_date` and `expiry_date`. and then whenever he goes on the site we create an entry in the `onlineuserhistory` table, so for a date 11/1/2016 to 11/15/2016 he will have one record in `onlineuser` table and five records in `onlineuserhistory` table as he might have visited it 5 times.
Now when the month is up like if he went to site on 11/16/2016 the `onlineuser` will change the dates as only one record can exist for that merchant and that user.

For reporting purpose I need to check if at least one record exists in `onlineuserhistory` table. The person who wrote earlier he wrote it with left join to `onlieuser` table.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalNumPurchases
FROM Transactions t
INNER JOIN Merchants m ON m.MerchantID = t.FromEntityID AND  
m.StatusID = 8 AND m.IsHidden = 0
INNER JOIN MerchantLocations ml ON m.MerchantID = ml.MerchantID
INNER JOIN Accounts AS a on t.ToEntityID = a.AccountID
LEFT JOIN onlineuser au ON m.MerchantID = au.MerchantID and 
a.ManagerUserID = au.UserID
a.ManagerUserID = au.UserID  
WHERE t.ToEntityTypeID = 5
AND t.TransactionDate BETWEEN '2016-11-11 07:00:00' AND '2016-11-15 06:59:59'
```

How do I update this so that I can do a check on `onlineuserhistory` table to check if at least one record exists there in that date range, and if more than one record exists then also I should consider 1 record for that.

Comment: Why do you need to do this check? If they have any transactions, doesn't that mean they must have been online during the period?

Comment: You could just add a subquery `select count(*) from onlineuserhistory where date between 'xxx' and 'yyy'`

Comment: Where do I add a subquery? inside the join?

Comment: You can do that, or you can just put it in the `SELECT` clause: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalNumPurchases, (SELECT COUNT(*) > 0 FROM ...) AS anyonline ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a subquery that returns whether anyone was online during the period.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalNumPurchases,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) > 0
         FROM onlineuserhistory
         WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-11-11 07:00:00' AND '2016-11-15 06:59:59') AS anyOnline
FROM Transactions t
INNER JOIN Merchants m ON m.MerchantID = t.FromEntityID AND  
m.StatusID = 8 AND m.IsHidden = 0
INNER JOIN MerchantLocations ml ON m.MerchantID = ml.MerchantID
INNER JOIN Accounts AS a on t.ToEntityID = a.AccountID
LEFT JOIN onlineuser au ON m.MerchantID = au.MerchantID and 
    a.ManagerUserID = au.UserID
WHERE t.ToEntityTypeID = 5
AND t.TransactionDate BETWEEN '2016-11-11 07:00:00' AND '2016-11-15 06:59:59'
```

Comment: I don't want it a seprate select, the totalnumPurchases count should vary

Comment: Vary in what way? Your query is not grouped by anything, it's just a total number for all merchants, so I thought you wanted to know whether anyone was online in any account. The question is not clear, I did my best to understand it. It would help if you showed some sample data and the desired result.